# Android: Adding functionality that activty changes when game is complete

Tags: android

I wish to add the following functionality to my game:

-When the game is **complete** (no more cards are visible on screen) then move to a **new activity**

I am aware how to move to another activty using intents but I am not sure how to implement the functionality in this case.

I.e. what variable/info can I use to ensure the game is complete when I move before moving to the next activity?

For reference, The game is based off [this open source game](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/07/29/memory-game-android-application/) Images of the game are shown here to give an idea.

Current code:

```
public class Manager extends Activity {
    private static int ROW_COUNT = -1;
    private static int COL_COUNT = -1;
    private Context context;
    private Drawable backImage;
    private int [] [] cards;
    private List<Drawable> images;
    private Card firstCard;
    private Card seconedCard;
    private ButtonListener buttonListener;

    private static Object lock = new Object();

    int turns;
    private TableLayout mainTable;
    private UpdateCardsHandler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        handler = new UpdateCardsHandler();
        loadImages();
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView url = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myWebSite));
        Linkify.addLinks(url, Linkify.WEB_URLS);

       backImage =  getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);

       /*
       ((Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonNew)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            newGame();

        }


    });*/

       buttonListener = new ButtonListener();

        mainTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayout03);


        context  = mainTable.getContext();

         Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);


            s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

              @Override
              public void onItemSelected(
                      android.widget.AdapterView<?> arg0, 
                      View arg1, int pos, long arg3){

                  ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01)).setSelection(0);

                int x,y;

                switch (pos) {
                case 1:
                    x=4;y=4;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    x=4;y=5;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    x=4;y=6;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    x=5;y=6;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    x=6;y=6;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
                }
                newGame(x,y);

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }

    private void newGame(int c, int r) {
        ROW_COUNT = r;
        COL_COUNT = c;

        cards = new int [COL_COUNT] [ROW_COUNT];


        mainTable.removeView(findViewById(R.id.TableRow01));
        mainTable.removeView(findViewById(R.id.TableRow02));

        TableRow tr = ((TableRow)findViewById(R.id.TableRow03));
        tr.removeAllViews();

        mainTable = new TableLayout(context);
        tr.addView(mainTable);

         for (int y = 0; y < ROW_COUNT; y++) {
             mainTable.addView(createRow(y));
          }

         firstCard=null;
         loadCards();

         turns=0;
         ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText("Tries: "+turns);


    }

    private void loadImages() {
        images = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card1));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card2));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card3));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card4));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card5));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card6));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card7));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card8));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card9));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card10));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card11));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card12));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card13));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card14));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card15));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card16));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card17));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card18));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card19));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card20));
        images.add(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.card21));

    }

    private void loadCards(){
        try{
            int size = ROW_COUNT*COL_COUNT;

            Log.i("loadCards()","size=" + size);

            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                list.add(new Integer(i));
            }


            Random r = new Random();

            for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
                int t=0;

                if(i>0){
                    t = r.nextInt(i);
                }

                t=list.remove(t).intValue();
                cards[i%COL_COUNT][i/COL_COUNT]=t%(size/2);

                Log.i("loadCards()", "card["+(i%COL_COUNT)+
                        "]["+(i/COL_COUNT)+"]=" + cards[i%COL_COUNT][i/COL_COUNT]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("loadCards()", e+"");
        }

    }

    private TableRow createRow(int y){
         TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
         row.setHorizontalGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

         for (int x = 0; x < COL_COUNT; x++) {
                 row.addView(createImageButton(x,y));
         }
         return row;
    }

    private View createImageButton(int x, int y){
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
        button.setId(100*x+y);
        button.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        return button;
    }

    class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            synchronized (lock) {
                if(firstCard!=null && seconedCard != null){
                    return;
                }
                int id = v.getId();
                int x = id/100;
                int y = id%100;
                turnCard((Button)v,x,y);
            }

        }

        private void turnCard(Button button,int x, int y) {
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(images.get(cards[x][y]));

            if(firstCard==null){
                firstCard = new Card(button,x,y);
            }
            else{ 

                if(firstCard.x == x && firstCard.y == y){
                    return; //the user pressed the same card
                }

                seconedCard = new Card(button,x,y);

                turns++;
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1)).setText("Tries: "+turns);


                TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            synchronized (lock) {
                              handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("E1", e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                };

                  Timer t = new Timer(false);
                    t.schedule(tt, 1300);
            }


           }

        }

    class UpdateCardsHandler extends Handler{

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                checkCards();
            }
        }
         public void checkCards(){
                if(cards[seconedCard.x][seconedCard.y] == cards[firstCard.x][firstCard.y]){
                    firstCard.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    seconedCard.button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    seconedCard.button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
                    firstCard.button.setBackgroundDrawable(backImage);
                }

                firstCard=null;
                seconedCard=null;
            }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to check win conditions with an if statement. This should be done in the method when a turn is actually taken which I assume happens in the turnCard() method.

```
if (winConditionMet) {
    displayWinningScreen();
} else if (lossConditionMet) {
    displayLosingScreen();
}
```

If conditions have been met, then call a method which handles wrapping up that screen, and then launching a new activity. For instance you could add a button to the screen with whatever text you wanted, that when pushed, would take the user to the next screen, be it your score screen, replay screen, main menu, or what have you.

Edit: Okay, since this is a game of memory, you could iterate through the cards at the end of every turn taken and check if any card still has its image set to backImage. If there are none left that are set to backImage, you can then end the game with your code inside of the if statement.

Or, instead of using an ArrayList, you could use some form of Map to keep track of if each card has been permanently turned up or not with the boolean value.